# dependency error in R package

Tags: linux, r, ggplot2, installation, install.packages

Everytime I give the command for any package, in this case for ggplot2, I get this after a few minutes. I am missing something, but can't figure out what. Thanks in advance!

```
ERROR: dependency ‘plyr’ is not available for package ‘reshape2’
* removing ‘/home/cj/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/reshape2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘reshape2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘plyr’ is not available for package ‘scales’
* removing ‘/home/cj/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/scales’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘plyr’, ‘reshape2’, ‘scales’ are not available for package ‘ggplot2’
* removing ‘/home/cj/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/ggplot2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpAXVGC6/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: What does *give the command for any package* mean?  Where's your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on R 2.14. Please please PLEASE upgrade to something from the last few years -- preferably from the *current year* such as R 3.2.0, 3.2.1 or the recently-release 3.2.2.

Simply put, you are being unreasonable in trying to expect that *current* and well-maintained archived for users of the *current* versions should also work with versions released that many years ago.